# Is it ever appropriate to add an ICommand to your domain model objects?

Tags: mvvm

I'm working on applying the MVVM pattern (and learning it in the process) for a Windows Store application.

Right now I am leaning towards having a 1:1 correspondence between View and ViewModel, where multiple ViewModels have a dependency on the same underlying Model.

For example, suppose I have an entity "Student".  I have two ways to view the student: in a full-screen details page or as a list of students in a classroom.  That results in the following View/ViewModel pairs:

- StudentDetailsView/StudentDetailsViewModel
- StudentListItemView/StudentListItemViewModel

At the moment I'm assuming my ViewModel will directly expose the Model, and my Xaml will bind to ViewModel.Model.property-name (I realize that's debatable).

Suppose I can perform some action on the Student from either View (e.g., "Graduate").  I want to have the Graduate behavior in my Model (to avoid an Anemic Domain Model), and I want to avoid duplicating behavior between ViewModels that depend on the same Model.

My intent is to have an ICommand (e.g., a RelayCommand) that I can bind a Graduate button to in the View.  Here's my question:

**Is there any reason not to make the ICommand a property of the Model class?**

Basically that would mean something like the following (ignoring the need for a Repository):

```
public class Student {
    public ICommand GraduateCommand { get { ... } }
    void Graduate() { ... }
}
```

That way both StudentDetailsView and StudentListItemsView could have Xaml that binds to that command (where DataContext is StudentViewModel and Model is the public property):

```
<Button Command="{Binding Model.GraduateCommand}" />
```

Obviously I could just make Student::Graduate() public, create duplicate GraduateCommands on the two ViewModels, and have the execution delegate call Model.Graduate().  But what would be the disadvantage of exposing the behavior of the class via an ICommand rather than a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a model's property in your view, then you should stop calling that MVVM. You can move graduate command implementation into another class (let's say a Helper class) an share it between your ViewModels (during the initialisation).

```
GraduateCommand=new RelayCommand (GraduateHelper.Graduate, CanGraduate);
```

Wrong: put Graduate() into your entity.

**EDIT**

Extension methods for INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public static class NotifyExtension
{
    public static void OnPropertyChanged(this INotifyPropertyChanged source, PropertyChangedEventHandler h, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = h;
        if (handler != null) handler(source, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public static bool SetProperty<T>(this INotifyPropertyChanged source,PropertyChangedEventHandler handler, ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        source.OnPropertyChanged(handler, propertyName);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And then :

```
public class Student:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = "Name";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set {
            this.SetProperty<string>(PropertyChanged, ref _name, value, "Name");            }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public partial class MyViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Student _student=new Student();
    public Student Student
    {
        get { return _student; }
        set
        {
            this.SetProperty<Student>(PropertyChanged, ref _student, value, "Student");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        

}
```

Finally Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Student.Name}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why it would be wrong to put Graduate() in the Model?  It's an artificial example I came up with on the spur of the moment, but my goal is to demonstrate that there is behavior in the Model layer, obeying the principle that a Model with no behavior is exhibiting the Anemic Domain Model anti-pattern.

Comment: Firstly, we use MVVM to make the code : 
-> Readable - easy to understand
-> Easy to unit test
-> Maintainable by decoupling the components thus limiting the impact of code changes.
So the view and model should never reference each other directly.
Secondly, I don't think ADM is an anti-pattern, whatever Fowler may think. If you are a java or .Net (C#, Wpf) developper, It's better to write a SOLID compliant code than writing Rich Domain Models. I don't deny that their are arguments for Fowler... but I have yet to be convinced. So I'm all ears

Comment: I may clarify something here: the model in MVVM is not "behaviour less" (model may not mean Entity). You can embed a model inside a ViewModel and bind directly a model method with the Command.
`GraduateCommand=new RelayCommand (this.studentModel.Graduate, CanGraduate);`

Comment: I'm torn on accessing the Model from the View (via the ViewModel).  I do understand some of the reasons why that can be bad.  But my domain objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and I foresee a lot of code in the ViewModel to delegate property sets/gets to the Model, in addition to being forced to hook model.PropertyChanged throughout the ViewModels to handle cases where the change to a property occurs in the data layer (so that the property change notification will be propagated to the bindings in the View layer).

Comment: If your "model" already implement INotifyPropertyChanged then you don't need to do things twice. Bind directly. See code in my answer

Comment: That's exactly what I meant I was doing, by the way.  ViewModel.Model, in essence.  So StudentViewModel would have a StudentModel property, and could bind to that (e.g. Text="{Binding StudentModel.FirstName}").  Which gets back to the original question.  If I'm binding to StudentModel.FirstName, why not bind to StudentModel.GraduateCommand rather than creating the GraduateCommand in multiple ViewModel classes or creating a GraduateHelper class?  Wait...just saw your edited answer...checking it out now.

Comment: Yes, your code shows essentially what I'm doing.  And therefore my question still applies about pushing the GraduateCommand into the Student class.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in many cases, **it is perfectly fine to bind directly from the View to the Model**, if you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the Model. It would still be MVVM. This prevents the ViewModel to be cluttered with a lot of "relay-directly-to-Model" code. You only include in the VM what can't be directly used by the View (need to wrap/denormalize/transform data, or Model properties don't implement INPC, or you need another validation layer...).

**That said**, Commands are a primary mean of communication between the View and the ViewModel.

- There may be many receivers for the command (possibly on different ViewModels).
- The Execute/CanExecute pattern often doesn't fit outside of the context of the VM.
- Even if the real stuff is done in a method of the Model, Commands may have some logic other than just delegating to the model (validation, interaction with other VM properties/methods...).
- When it comes to test your VMs, you can't stub the commands' behavior if they're outside of the VM.

For these reasons, **Commands do not belong to the Model**.

If you're concerned by code duplication across VMs, you can create a `StudentViewModel` from which both `StudentDetailsViewModel` and `StudentListItemViewModel` will inherit. `StudentViewModel` will define the Command and its common behavior.

Comment: Binding a View to to a Model is not a good practice in MVVM. The Model is for Business Data and Business Logic. And that's all. It should never deal with the view directly. For example, if your business logic changes (let say you simply updated the name of a method), You will be obliged to update the view's code (search in Xaml and update as the refractor doesn't understand everything).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Patrice.  I tend to agree, but you made some good points and helped clarify my thinking about why I agree.  :-)

Comment: @LeMara If you change the name of the Command, you'll have to update the View, whether the Command is defined on the Model or the VM. The underlying method (to which the Command delegates) will be refactored perfectly fine, wherever it is located. As for the general advice "Binding to a Model is not a good practice in MVVM", you should not have such a strict vision of the pattern. Laurent Bugnion (creator of the MVVM Light Toolkit) regularly stands for the same position as mine, as was Josh Smith when he was a MVVM evangelist. It is just perfectly convenient and it has few or no drawbacks.

Comment: I was not talking about the command but the business logiciel method which is in C# as well as the ViewModel...

Comment: @LeMara So you're talking about properties, not methods. You're right, but I suspect that, if you use a VM as a relayer, the name of the binded property on the VM should also change for consistency... But I agree, this is still a drawback, cause at least it will not "crash" at runtime. Anyway, I should point out that I am really not a fan of the "binding to Model" way. Here is why: VMs should be *small*. If you find yourself binding to a huge amount of Model properties, this is often a smell. You should consider splitting your UI into more parts (user controls, or Regions, using PRISM).

Comment: BTW, the question was about Commands. There is no debate for Commands ;)